# git bash suddenly slow on every command not only git command

Tags: windows, git-bash

I have git bash in WIN 10. Since last week suddenly every command (ls, cd, git, ...) runs very slow, even ctrl-c. After type a command it pauses, and then shows result, before command completes, it pauses another while. I remembered last week there was a 3D Graphics GPU something in notification corner during that time. I checked that I don't have GPU in this PC, and it is GeForce 630 with a 2017 driver. (heard that AMD driver can cause such problem).

Comment: To understand where is the problem lies in, it would be a windows 10 build (please specify the version, as sometimes they publish broken builds at some point), then try looking into Event viewer in windows 10(control panel=>administration tools=>event viewer) after you have run the command. Then try checking windows logs (application logs and system logs). Also it would be great if you could check if it works in cmd or powers he'll CLI(if they gave similar issue). You could also try: reinstall of git bash, windows 10 or try updating it. Check how many resources you have in the task manager.

Comment: Try closing everything except the git bash. as another try you could go into the safe mode in windows 10(it loads only necessary configuration) https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-10-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234. please let me know of anything of the given solution will provide you with any additional information or to continue the investigation, or even solve the problem, then we could move it to the answer section

Comment: If you have some recent program installation in the (control panel => programs and features), try uninstalling it after which you may have noticed this behavior

Comment: @UtmostCreator I did what you said one by one. In Event viewer application logs and system logs, what should I do next? cmd and PowerShell do not have this problem. Reinstall Git bash still have this problem. System updates is automatically for Windows 10, that's why I didn't recover the OS, because it would install the same updates and results the same slow Git bash.

Comment: @UtmostCreator In safe mode, git bash runs normally (fast). Besides, msconfig in cmd, under "startup options" -> "diagnostic startup" (load basic devices and services only), start PC with this choice, git bash also runs fast. But start PC with "normal startup" option, git Bash runs super slow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1348691/tiina 1 have you found something in `Event viewer`? 2 If safe mode works w/o issues, then for sure some of your processes cause it.3 Do you have some anti-virus software? (try disabling it for a test),you'd better check the lastly installed software (as w/o seeing the whole config this is hard to debug.4[i have found this source](https://groups.google.com/g/git-for-windows/c/hHzDoeVLHSI)and you could [disable auto-update in windows 10](https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/disable-update-windows-10.html), probably the best way is to use `Group Policy Editor`

Comment: I may suggest you switch to [Windows Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701), I have been using it since its release, and I am pretty much satisfied with it.  Also, you could use WLS2 inside Windows Terminal. The best way. Provide the community with your git bash version and windows version and build in the description of the question, it may increase changes to resolve the problem if someone else encountered a similar issue. Again, try removing some of the recently installed software (but 1stly try to disable any anti-virus software for a test)

Comment: If it is a driver you could try rolling back in the `Device Manager` menu (`WIN+X => Device Manager=>` RMB on your GPU `Driver` Tab, then select `Rollback option`. This sentence is not clear enough: *"I checked that I don't have GPU in this PC, and it is GeForce 630 with a 2017 driver. (heard that AMD driver can cause such problem)."*, if you have drivers for Nvidia and Radeon, ofc. this could cause the issue.

Comment: @UtmostCreator I did open event viewer. But I don't understand what I should find. *have you found something in Event viewer?*. But thanks to you, msconfig, services I did find that by disabling all services I can have a fast bash, so it must be one of the services. Before I try out which service, this week the bash slowed down problem is suddenly gone. I think maybe it is updated or some confliction solved. You may leave msconfig check services and safe mode and `startup` with different options as an answer. That would close our discussion for now I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Things we should try these steps in its order:

1. Booting into a safe mode - to make sure if the windows may work w/o issues with this software;
2. Reintalling of `git bash`;
3. Checking the `Event Viewer` - so see if anything specific to the git bash application is logged there;
4. Uninstalling any recent software you have installed last session or two;
5. Disabling all auto-load programs and anti-viruses/windows defender (just for the sake of test) - in most cases that shouldn't be an issue;
6. Try using `Restore point` if you have any;
7. reinstalling windows 10 (least desireable probably).

#### 1 Safe Mode | Try closing everything except the git bash or as an alternative, you could go into the safe mode in windows 10

How to do that see [here; it loads only necessary configuration](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-10-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234)

#### 2 Reintalling of `git bash`

Is most straghforward way to resolve this;

Open Event viewer in windows 10 by chosing of the following methods:

- `control panel`=>`administration tools`=>`event viewer`);
- (By opening the search and typing|<kbd>Win</kbd>=> just type `event viewer`) - "`event viewer`";
- by opening **Run command** (using <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> => `eventvwr`);

#### 3 Checking the `Event Viewer`

Then try checking windows logs:

- application logs - records events related to Windows system
  components, such as drivers and built-in interface elements;
- system logs - records events related to programs installed on the system.

You must be looking at the column **Level** (`Error`) after you have tried to run the commands (that freezes you git bash). Look at the date and time column to check the most recent one.

Then by going to `eventvwr` you may see some new warning/error (most probably that hangs up your console)
See the `Event viewer` error example (you could use error message and Event ID to google the problem):
[image]

#### 4 Uninstalling any recent software

`control panel` => `programs and features` - try uninstalling it after which you may have noticed this behavior.

please let us know if anything of the given solution works or provides you with any additional information to continue the investigation. Or even solve the problem.

#### 5 Disabling all auto-load programs and anti-viruses/windows defender

1. Open your `Task manager`;
2. Go to `Starup` tab;
3. Disable everything you have there.

On the legacy Windows 10 [for windows 10 users **under** 20h2]:
<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> => `Startup` tab;

See [How to Stop Windows 10 Apps From Launching at Startup](https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/stop-windows-10-apps-from-launching-at-startup)

#### 6 Try using `Restore point` if you have any

See [Recovery options in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/recovery-options-in-windows-31ce2444-7de3-818c-d626-e3b5a3024da5#:%7E:text=In%20the%20Control%20Panel%20search,select%20Scan%20for%20affected%20programs.)

#### 7 Reinstalling windows

By going to the [windows 10 website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and downloading the tool in the `Create Windows 10 installation media` section.

Comment: if you vote down, please be kind to explain why, or just try to improve the answer